# Google Access on WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, oauth-2.0

I am having problems building an app that can access google accounts. I have the following code that gets the sign in [image: Signin Page] page for google accounts and then the access permissions page is also displayed![image]. Once i click on "Allow Access" the app is redirected to error page[image: Error]. here are few screenshots so that whoever is trying to help can understand better.. and below is the code that am using

```
 private void browseGoogle_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string address = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth" +
        "?client_id=" + "*******.apps.googleusercontent.com" +
        "&scope=" + "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me" +
        "&response_type=code" +
         "&redirect_uri=" + "https://www.****.com/oauth2callback";

        browseGoogle.Navigate(new Uri(address, UriKind.Absolute));

    }
```

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?as=634f855389bf10ff&hl=en_GB&xsrfsign=APsBz4gAAAAAUHZvwB3xTqisyv8hEcWem5X3eKvwAHN9
this is the URI its navigating to after allow access is selected/clicked. What does this mean?

This is all am doing. My BrowserNavigated Method doesn't contain any code as of now. I dunno what to do further.hence seeking help.
Please help me resolve  this issue.. All answers and suggestion appreciated.

Comment: does the url set to redirect_uri exist ?
what happens if you navigate directly to that url ?

Comment: That URL is dummy.. It is the same URL i used for my twitter access app also... You think thats the mistake??? what should be the redirect URL given in this case then?

Comment: or set the redirect_uri param to "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" it will navigate to google's default redirect page.

Comment: if you don't have a webpage to handle the callback, why enter it in the redirect_uri param, that parameter specifies the page to be redirected after the authorization. if you don't have one then set it to "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
*EDIT* your email address is visible in the screenshot :)

Comment: But that has to be set on https://code.google.com/apis right?? as the client settings.. ?? i mean the client settings redirect URI and my redirect uri in the code should match right?

Comment: I get this msg "Redirect URL "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" is not allowed for this type of OAuth 2 client." when i try to do wat u suggested..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17853/discussion-between-apoorva-and-vignesh-natraj)

Comment: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?as=3ef3e0d20763a600&hl=en_GB&xsrfsign=APsBz4gAAAAAUHZ1v2-BSzoZbJ0oVvqIiLqtbEOVbKr2" What is this?

Comment: @Apoorva - What is What?

Comment: @Ramhound If u click on that URL u sill see that the URL has a key "xsrfsign" with some value. I wanted to knw what that was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 private void browseGoogle_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        try
        {
            StringBuilder autheticateURL = new StringBuilder();
            autheticateURL.Append(GmailSettings.AuthorizeUri).Append("?client_id=").Append(GmailSettings.clientID).Append("&scope=").
                Append(GmailSettings.ScopeValue).Append("&response_type=code").Append("&redirect_uri=").Append(GmailSettings.CallbackUri);
            browseGoogle.Navigate(new Uri(autheticateURL.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Logger.log(TAG, "browseGoogle_Loaded()", ex.Message);

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called when the web browser initiates Navigation to various pages 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">Browser</param>
    /// <param name="e">Navigating event arguments</param>
    private void browseGoogle_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string hostName = e.Uri.Host;
            string URL = e.Uri.ToString();

            if (hostName.StartsWith("localhost"))
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/HomePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Logger.log(TAG, "browseGoogle_Navigating()", ex.Message);

        }
    }
```

The XAML goes like this

```
  <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="browseGoogle" Loaded="browseGoogle_Loaded" IsScriptEnabled="true" Navigating="browseGoogle_Navigating" />
```

My mistakes were two:-
1) as vignesh has mentioned in his comments I was using a wrong Redirect URI. 
2)IsScriptEnabled was not at all set in my Web Browser Controls. Once i set it true everything was fine.

Answer (score 2):

Just check the GDrive open-source application code [here](https://github.com/PedroLamas/GDrive).

The Authorization [View](https://github.com/PedroLamas/GDrive/blob/master/PedroLamas.WP7.GDrive/View/AuthorizationPage.xaml) and [ViewModel](https://github.com/PedroLamas/GDrive/blob/master/PedroLamas.WP7.GDrive/ViewModel/AuthorizationViewModel.cs) show you how you can make OAuth sign-in with Google credentials.

Download the code, read the pre-build instructions on the site, and test it!

Comment: Its working with the same code as above with very minor changes. It started working as soon as i added IsScriptEnabled="True" in the web browser control which i had missed.. Thanks for the Suggestion :)

Comment: Great, glad the problem is fixed!! :)